# Overriding Joomla core component file

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I am trying to override the com_content/views/article/view.html.php file in joomla using the instructions given in this [page](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_component_mvc_from_the_Joomla!_core)

It says I have to create a folder named 'code' in base directory and create the same directory structure. I tried it , but its not working. Can someone confirm whether its working.

Where should I create code folder? Is  it on root of joomla installations?

PS- The edit is working correctly when applied on core file

Comment: Have you tried doing the templating method as well?

Comment: Templating method also not working. I think templating method can only override default.php files inside tmpl folder.

Comment: What version of Joomla are you using?

Answer (score 8):

You can override (nearly) any class in Joomla, if your class with **the same name** is loaded first. To ensure that, you need to create a system plugin.

Here is an example for root/components/com_content/views/article/view.html.php:

```
class plgSystemOverride extends JPlugin
{
    public function onAfterRoute()
    {
        JLoader::register('ContentViewArticle', 'path/to/override.php', true);
    } 
}
```

CAVEAT: Overriding a core class can lead to problems with other extensions, if you're not very careful. For views, though, any interferrence with other extensions is less likely.

Comment: Awesomesauce. Nice answer

Answer (score 1):

You can't override component controllers, models and views in core Joomla! without using a 3rd party plugin.

The plugin you need can be found here: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/style-a-design/templating/15611

The code folder then goes into your Joomla root unless you're overriding a back-end view in which case it goes into /administrator

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Class Overrider Plugin http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/tools/development-tools/23994

just adding some simple human reading commands